# Why can't I assemble this single FPU instruction with GNU as?

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, gnu-assembler, armv7

I'm trying to retrieve the binary representation of a few FPU instructions for the Cortex-M4 processor. I resolved to put the code I need to retrieve in a file like this

```
.syntax unified
vsub.f32 s0, s1, s2    ; or any other instruction
```

and then call

```bash
arm-none-eabi-as -o /dev/null -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard -al -EB <file>
```

However, for FPU instructions, it fails telling me

```
Assembler messages:
Error: invalid instruction shape -- `vsub.f32 s0,s1,s2'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: BTW, `@` is the comment character for ARM, not `;`.  I assume the error message would have been different if you actually had a `; comment` in your source file, so that's not it, but you probably want to edit.  (`;` is a statement / instruction separator, like newline).

Comment: Yup, what fuz said.  `arm-none-eabi-gcc -c foo.s -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard` assembles it without complaint.  (Both `cpu` and `float-abi` options were necessary.  Without float-abi I guess it assumes an M4 without the optional FPU)

Comment: @PeterCordes Doesn't work for me funnily enough.  Which is why I removed my earlier comment.  Clang assembles it just fine though.

Comment: @fuz: My `arm-none-eabi-gcc` is version 13.2, invoking `arm-none-eabi-as` from Binutils 2.41, on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux

Comment: @PeterCordes Here's it's GNU assembler 2.40, arm-none-eabi-gcc 11.3.0 (as supplied by FreeBSD ports).  The update to binutils 2.41 hasn't made it's way into ports yet, perhaps whatever bug there is has been fixed since.

Comment: @PeterCordes you're right, I asked Emacs to place a comment and it used `;`. Anyway the real file doesn't have the comment, so that's not the issue. But I think I found something, see my answer

Comment: @fuz: I'd guess it might be `gcc` passing different options to `as`, so maybe it's the GCC version that mattered.  Or possibly a different config of defaults.  `arm-...gcc -v ...`  showed it running `.../arm-none-eabi/bin/as -v -march=armv7e-m+fp -mfloat-abi=hard -meabi=5`.  If those are the same options your GCC passes, then yeah it's presumably the GAS version that makes the difference.

Comment: @PeterCordes My `arm-none-eabi-gcc` seems to omit the `+fp` bit from `-march=armv7e-m+fp` when it invokes `as`.  If I manually add this, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the `-mfpu` flag is needed too (in this case, `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16`):

```
[alessandro@commodoroII src]$ arm-none-eabi-as -o /dev/null -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard -al -EB /tmp/temp-julia.s
/tmp/temp-julia.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/temp-julia.s:2: Error: invalid instruction shape -- `vsub.f32 s0,s1,s2'
ARM GAS  /tmp/temp-julia.s                      page 1


   1                    .syntax unified
   2                    vsub.f32 s0, s1, s2
[alessandro@commodoroII src]$ arm-none-eabi-as -o /dev/null -mcpu=cortex-m4 -march=armv7e-m -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -al -EB /tmp/temp-julia.s
ARM GAS  /tmp/temp-julia.s                      page 1


   1                    .syntax unified
   2 0000 EE300AC1      vsub.f32 s0, s1, s2
```

Comment: You don't need `-march=armv7e-m`; that's implied by `-mcpu=cortex-m4`.  (Or with your other options, probably implying `-march=armv7e-m+fp`)

Comment: Uhm, I don't think I'm getting it. If it's implied, what is the difference between the working and the non working versions?

Comment: The difference is the `-mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16` option.  That's what was necessary to tell it your M4 has an FPU.  (The `-mcpu` and `-mfloat-abi` options are also necessary.  Or I guess you could probably use `-march` instead of `-mcpu` here, but I'd recommend using `-mcpu`.  I don't think there's any need or benefit to specify both)